# Bootstrap: Popover dismiss not working in iOS browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Bootstrap Popover and added JS code for popover dismiss on tap in the body. It works on Android but not iOS.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").tooltip({   
    selector: "[data-toggle='tooltip']",
    container: "body"
  })
  .popover({
    selector: "[data-toggle='popover']",
    container: "body",
    html: true
  });
});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
    if(!$(this).is(e.target) &&
       $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&
       $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="width:400px; height:400px; background:#000;padding-top:50px;">
  <a data-placement="top" role="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Popover" data-original-title="" title="">
    Click here
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:

```
<script>
$("[data-toggle=popover]")
 .popover({
  html: true
 });

$('a[data-toggle=popover]')
 .popover();

$(':not(#anywhereonthepage)').click(function(e)

 {
  e.preventDefault()

  $('a[data-toggle=popover]').each(function()

   {

    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('a[data-toggle=popover]').has(e.target).length === 0) {
     $(this).popover('hide');
     return;
    }
   });
 });
</script>
```